# Environment or command to inject in preauthor/postauthor to not print the author?

Tags: environments, author, titling, hide

For a personalized class and some internal magic, I would like to define `preauthor/postauthor` in the `titling` package such that the user can define the author, but it will not be printed.

Currently, the two versions are :

There is an author :

```
\author{AAA}
```

There is no author:

```
\preauthor{}
\author{}
\postauthor{}
```

I would like to replace X and Y by something so that even if an author is provided, it is not printed?

```
\preauthor{X}
\author{AAA}
\postauthor{X}
```

Comment: Please provide code we can compile to test with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested since you've provided no code:

```
\makeatletter
\preauthor{\let\@authorsaved\@author \let\@author\relax}
\postauthor{\let\@author\@authorsaved}
\makeatother
```

But you should not use this method if your purpose is anonymisation, for example. In that case, it's probably best to just discard the information immediately and perhaps write a warning to the terminal.